# Sort order of group as Parent & Child in Alphabetical Order

Tags: mysql

I have following values in table

```
id       | name      | parent_id |

1        | test      | 0         |
2        | test1     | 3         |
3        | test2     | 1         |
4        | test3     | 3         |
5        | test3     | 4         |
```

so I want output like

```
id       | name      | parent_id |

1        | test      | 0         |
3        | test2     | 1         |
2        | test1     | 3         |
4        | test3     | 3         |
5        | test3     | 4         |
```

means sort order so that table has a parent, it is listed below its parent, in alpha order .

I have tried following query but not working:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY coalesce(parent_id, id), name
```

Pl. help. Thanks in advance

Comment: You would need the ASC keyword for lowest to highest value.

Comment: I need value sorted in alpha order and if value has child,come after parent